# Have description have a limit of the amount of characters on the page. PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Okay, so I'm working on a PHP site, I have descriptions of the product under the image, what I'm need to do is limit the amount of characters on the page and add a click here or.. For the viewers to be directed to that products page to see the full description. FYI very new to PHP, here is what I have so far. So question is do I use PHP or javascript or both and how do I do that ?

```
<?php
// Include need php scripts
require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php");
require_once ("Includes/connectDB.php");
include ("Includes/header.php");
if (!empty($_GET['cat'])) {
    $category = $_GET['cat'];
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '".$category."'");
} else {
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM products");
}
if (!$query) {
    die('Database query failed: ' . $query->error);
} 
?>
<section>
    <div id="productList">
        <?php
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($row_count == 0) {
            echo '<p style="color:red">There are no images uploaded for this category</p>';
        } elseif ($query) {
            while($products = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){             
                $file = $products['image'];
                $product_name = $products['product'];
                $image_id = $products['id'];
                $price = $products['price'];
                $desc = $products['description'];
                echo '<div class="image_container">';
                echo '<a href="viewProduct.php?id=' . $image_id . '"><p><img src="Images/products/'.$file.'" alt="'.$product_name.'" height="250" /></p>';
                echo $product_name . "</a><br>$" . $price . "<br>" . $desc;
                echo '</div>';
                if (is_admin()){
                    echo "<a href='deleteproduct.php'><button>delete</button></a>";
                }
            } 
        } else {
            die('There was a problem with the query: ' .$query->error);             
        } 
        mysqli_free_result($query);     
        ?>
    </div>
</section>
<?php include ("Includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Not to seem rude, but it appears you may want to do some more learning on PHP and Javascript.

Udemy has some great courses for cheap.. there are also others out there..
I'm in no way endorsing Udemy.. but in the many online classes i have taken they are the best.. unless you want to spend a few grand

Answer (score 1):

using **strlen** and **substr** we can achieve this

```
$length = 150
$x = 'string';

 if(strlen($x)<=$length)
  {
    echo $x;
  }
  else
  {
    $y=substr($x,0,$length) . '...';
    echo $y;
  }
```